# Create simple_form in bootstrap modal with haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, haml, simple-form

I'm trying to use `simple_form` in a Bootstrap 3 modal in Ruby 2.5 on Rails (v5.1) with `haml` in the view.

I want to be able to put the submit button in the modal footer, but this breaks the `haml` conventions. Any workarounds?

**Modal**

```
#addDataModelModal.modal.fade{"aria-hidden" => "true", "aria-labelledby" => "exampleModalLabel", role: "dialog", tabindex: "-1"}
  .modal-dialog{role: "document"}
    .modal-content
      .modal-header
        %h5#addDataModelModalLabel.modal-title Choose a Data Model
        %button.close{"aria-label" => "Close", "data-dismiss" => "modal", type: "button"}
          %span{"aria-hidden" => "true"} ×
      .modal-body
        .text-center
          = simple_form_for @project, :url => add_project_datastores_project_path, :method => 'post' do |f|
            = f.input :project_datastores, collection: @datastores, label_method: :name, value_method: :datastore_sid, prompt: "Select a Data Model"
            = f.submit 'Add Data Model', :class => 'pull-right btn btn-primary'
      .modal-footer
        %button.btn.btn-secondary{"data-dismiss" => "modal", type: "button"} Close
        .text-center
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

start the `= simple_form_for` right below the `.modal-content` div so you can insert your `f` variable into all its children divs.

```
#addDataModelModal.modal.fade{"aria-hidden" => "true", "aria-labelledby" => "exampleModalLabel", role: "dialog", tabindex: "-1"}
  .modal-dialog{role: "document"}
    .modal-content
      = simple_form_for @project, :url => add_project_datastores_project_path, :method => 'post' do |f|
        .modal-header
          %h5#addDataModelModalLabel.modal-title Choose a Data Model
          %button.close{"aria-label" => "Close", "data-dismiss" => "modal", type: "button"}
            %span{"aria-hidden" => "true"} ×
        .modal-body
          .text-center
            = f.input :project_datastores, collection: @datastores, label_method: :name, value_method: :datastore_sid, prompt: "Select a Data Model"
        .modal-footer
          %button.btn.btn-secondary{"data-dismiss" => "modal", type: "button"} Close
          .text-center
            = f.submit 'Add Data Model', :class => 'pull-right btn btn-primary'
```

Comment: Cheers, Nick.  That sorted the problem.